# AttributeError: type object 'BlackPiece' has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

```
class BlackPiece(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, checkerType):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.CheckerType = checkerType

        if checkerType == 1:
            checkerImage = pygame.image.load('bp.png')
            self.image = pygame.Surface([100, 100])

        if checkerType == 2:
            checkerImage = pygame.image.load('bpKing.png')
            self.image = pygame.Surface([100, 100])

        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.image.blit(checkerImage,(0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        allSprites.append(self)

    def update(self, x, y): 
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    BlackPiece.update(BlackPiece, NewLocation[0], NewLocation[1])
```

I call the last line and get the error in the title. I'm so sure that it is something simple. The last line is within another subroutine. I have already created objects but I'm trying to edit the positions of them.

```
while i != 8:
    if i % 2 == 1:
        [x, y] = PieceLocation(i, 6)
        NewBP = BlackPiece(x, y, 1)
        blackPieces.add(NewBP)
        ObjectBoard.append(NewBP)
    else:
        [x, y] = PieceLocation(i, 5)
        NewBP = BlackPiece(x, y, 1)
        blackPieces.add(NewBP)
        ObjectBoard.append(NewBP)
        [x, y] = PieceLocation(i, 7)
        NewBP = BlackPiece(x, y, 1)
        blackPieces.add(NewBP)
        ObjectBoard.append(NewBP)
    i = i + 1
```

I use this first. Is this creating an instance? I have made a group to draw it and added it to an array for all my objects. I search through my object array and try to update it with this:

```
    BlackPiece.update(BlackPiece, NewLocation[0], NewLocation[1])
```

> line 61, in Update
>
> self.rect.x = x AttributeError: type object 'BlackPiece' has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: Why do you call `update` on the class? You should create an instance of the class `BlackPiece` and work with that.

Comment: To update the postion? I have already created the object with a position.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It's an honest mistake to not understand that one must make an instance of a class.

Comment: @Remolten Why would people downvote it but not even comment :(

Comment: It seems to me that you need more information about classes/object-oriented programming in Python. Take a look at [chapter 12](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=de#section_12) of Program Arcade Games (chapter 13 is about pygame sprites and also pretty helpful to learn oop). Your mistake was that you called `BlackPiece.update` on the class, but you first have to instantiate it, e.g. `black_piece = BlackPiece()`. Classes are just the blueprints for the instances/objects, you shouldn't use them directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(ObjectBoard)):
    if type(ObjectBoard[i]) == BlackPiece:
          NewLocation = PieceLocation(a, b)
          ObjectBoard[i].update(NewLocation[0], NewLocation[1])
```

I needed to use ObjectBoard[i]
thanks!